# NetApp ONTAP 7.1: Enable async on NFS export

Tags: nfs, netapp

Is there an `async` feature for NFS exports on NetApp ONTAP 7.1? If so, how can it be enabled?

The best search result I've found so far was an unanswered post on the NetApp forums:
https://communities.netapp.com/thread/34375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding what you're asking correctly:

The short answer is "No". The longer answer is "You don't need it".

NetApp filers cache NFS writes to NVRAM and acknowledge them to the host immediately, using that NVRAM to assemble full stripe writes and make good use of the Write Anywhere File Layout (WAFL).

What this means though, is that you're effectively doing `async` already - a write is deemed 'complete' as soon as it's committed in NVRAM, and the filer will handle destaging behind the scenes. (The NVRAM is battery backed in order to avoid potential data loss in a power outage).